# Event onclick on <td> and <tr> not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table and I want to have two different `onclick` on `tr` and only on `td`.

to do this I have two function:

```
function goToLink(url) {
    location.href = url ;
}

function goToLinkTd(e,url) {

    if (!e) var e = window.event;                // Get the window event
    e.cancelBubble = true;                       // IE Stop propagation
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
    location.href = url ;
}   

<tr onclick="goToLink('http://tahrircenter.com/product/bb/url')">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>10013</td>
    <td>عنوان</td>
    <td>
                                -
    </td>
    <td>10</td>


    <td>
        <p class="">0</p>
    </td>
    <td onclick="goToLinkTd(event,'http://tahrircenter.com/product/bb/url#price-change')">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://tahrircenter.com/assets/frontend/_img/_svg/chart.svg" alt="" class="table-chart"></a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

but when I click on my row(tr) it goes to td's link.

http://tahrircenter.com

Answer (score 0):

Use `jquery events` and give `tr` and `td` different classes

```
$(function(){
    $('tr td.someClass').click(function(){
         //Code here

    })

    $('tr.ClassName').click(function(){
         //Code here
        var attributeValue=$(this).attr("customName"); // you 
    })
})
```

Apply custom attribute in html

```
<tr customName="http://tahrircenter.com/product/bb/url">
   <td></td>
```